# Difference between $F[x]$ and $F(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Notation wise, what is the difference between $F[x]$ and $F(x)$? Is $F[x]$ the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $F$, and $F(x)$ the field of rational functions with coefficients in $F$?

I am asking because I am trying to determine if this statement is true or false:

An element of the field $F(x)$ of rational functions is transcendental
over $F$ if and only if it is not in $F$

and I'm not sure what an element of $F(x)$ not being in $F$ means.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $F[x]$ and $F(x)$ both contain copies of $F$ as the constant elements; $F[x]$ as a subring, $F(x)$ as a subfield.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right about the definitions. An element of $\mathbb R(x)$ not in $\mathbb R$ is for example $3x$. $3$ would be in $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R(x)$ at the same time.

In general, $F(x)$ contains $F[x]$ which in turn contains $F$.

Comment: But 3x would also be in R[x], yes? So R(x) should be a bigger field than R[x].

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jasper.

Comment: Can you explain why $F(x)$ contains $F[x]$? I am writing $F(x)=\{a+bx : a,b \in R\}$ so since $x$ is not in $F$ I think that $x^2$ is not in $F(x)$ for example.

Comment: @Ninja $x^2$ is a rational function, so it is in F(x).